# SMBus is always busy after HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT()

Tags: stm32cubemx, smbus

I'm using PMM240 power management board to control battery RRC-2054, and I have problem to use SMBus, please see the code I listed below, looks device is ready, but when you send something, it is always in busy(Master Data Transmission process is ongoing). Will this a matter of address problem, or a command problem, or others? anyway to get more info for this busy status?

```
if (HAL_SMBUS_IsDeviceReady(&hsmbus2, (uint16_t) PMM240_ADDRESS, 2, 2)
            != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();//passed
    }
uint32_t test = HAL_SMBUS_GetState(&hsmbus2);
        if (test != HAL_SMBUS_STATE_READY) {
            Error_Handler();//passed. 
        }
        ret = HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT(&hsmbus2,
                (uint16_t) PMM240_ADDRESS, &buffertx[0], 1,
                SMBUS_OTHER_FRAME_NO_PEC);

        if (ret != HAL_OK) {
            Error_Handler();//passed
        }
        // after enough time delay, 100 or 1000 ms
          HAL_Delay(100);//not useful for the following code.
       // inserting HAL_SMBUS_Init(&hsmbus2) could reset the busy status, but info lost, right?
        test = HAL_SMBUS_GetState(&hsmbus2);
        if (test != HAL_SMBUS_STATE_READY) {
            Error_Handler();//not passed
        }
```

Comment: Where are you waiting/testing for the SMBus operation to complete? Of course it is busy right after you start it. Or is that not the complete code? Which STM32 this is?

Comment: "// after enough time delay in debug mode" so I just run step by step and there are a few seconds delay between each command, I am runing stm32cubeMX on L476RG

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the function HAL_SMBUS_IsDeviceReady() is not working correctly. I used a different solution to search for devices on the bus. Maybe this will be useful.

```
// produce Start 
HAL_result = HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT(hsmbus, CheckingAddress, &value, 0, SMBUS_FIRST_FRAME);
//HAL_result = HAL_SMBUS_IsDeviceReady(hsmbus, CheckingAddress, 3, 100);
//while(HAL_SMBUS_GetState(hsmbus) != HAL_SMBUS_STATE_READY); // work without this line
if ( HAL_result == HAL_OK)
{
    //device is ready to connect
    .................. 
}
// finish transaction (may be not needed)
HAL_result = HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT(hsmbus, CheckingAddress, &value, 0, SMBUS_LAST_FRAME_NO_PEC);
```